# Redmine: How to link an attached file in a project from its underprojects?

Tags: file, hyperlink, attachment, redmine

Lets say I have Project A with an attached imageFile.

Then I created 10 different Projects which are underprojects of Project A.
I want to link the ImageFile of Project A to the Wiki of every underproject , so that I can see the ImageFile in the Wiki-Area of each underproject.

What im doing so far is to copy full path of the attached file of Project A in the Wiki of every underproject, like for example:

```
!>/attachments/download/157/schnittprofil.png!
```

Is there a better way to achieve that, because every time I update the imagefile, I have to renew the id-numbers of all imagefile-links in the underprojects.

Comment: Why don't you just refer to parent project's wiki from subprojects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an attachment is only actually identified by its ID and all attachments are immutable (i.e. can be changed after upload), new uploads will result in a new ID. Since multiple attachments with different IDs can have the same name, you can also not reliably find an attachment just by using its name in broad contexts.

That said, to solve your issue, you could use the `include` macro to include a common Wiki page in your sub-project's wiki pages which then displays the image attachment.

For that, you can create a Wiki page named e.g. `Schnittprofil` in your parent project where you directly upload your file. In the wiki page, just reference the image with

```
!schnittprofil.png!
```

Assuming the parent project has an identifier of `project-a`, you can then include the page in other wiki pages with

```
{{include(project-a:Schnittprofil)}}
```

Each time you change the page on the parent project, it will automatically also show the updated content on the child wikis. The only requirement is that the users need to be able to read the wiki of your parent project (e.g. are members of the project with the "Read wiki" permission).